Upgrade to Spring Boot 3 and in dependency heck. Can someone explain "omitted for duplicate" and "version managed from" in dep:tree -Dverbose
I've been fighting versions in maven all week, and I'm getting desperate.
I finally got it to compile, but there are somehow subtle differences that show up at runtime.  Specifically for the wiremock libraries.
Now I've got nearly everything working, but for some reason wiremock translates ? as %3f in my URLs, and I can't find anything about it.  I suspect there are two http libraries, one httpcomponent4 and the one I want is httpcomponent5.
I've tried generating a dependency tree, but I don't know what these mean
omitted for duplicate
version managed from
Any hints, clues, or guesses are appreciated.

Similar to this question. You might find useful information there (and if so, possibly this question is a duplicate of that one.
